# How can I run both a consumer and a publisher at the same time in Pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a Python application and I would like to run both a consumer and a publisher at the same time. Basically, I want to get a message via the `Consumer`, then parse it and process it and then send it back to RabbitMQ via the `Publisher`.

I have grabbed the code from the official Pika documentation for the [async consumer](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html) and the [async publisher](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html). They work individually, but I can't seem to make them work at the same time. In the starting point of the application I have:

```
import messaging.MQ as MQ

MQ.start_consumer()
MQ.start_publisher()
```

However, the `start_publisher()` line is never reached.

It looks like the culprit is this line in the `Consumer`:

```
self._connection.ioloop.start()
```

After that line gets called, nothing gets executed, apart from the asnyc methods defined in the `Consumer`.

I feel like this is very obvious, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: You have to put the publishing logic in your own on_message callback

Comment: @0x41ndrea: That might work, but would've required quite a bit of refactoring. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit awkward, but I solved this within 10 minutes after posting.

Basically, you just need to use threading. There may be an easier way, but this certainly works.

Following the examples in the documentation, for the `Consumer` one for example, you just need to replace:

```
class ExampleConsumer(object):
```

with:

```
import threading

class ExampleConsumer(threading.Thread):
```

Then you can simply run the threads:

```
publisher = Publisher()
consumer = Consumer()

publisher.start()
consumer.start()
```

I've also tweaked the `__init__` function and added some `Exception` catching, but tried to keep things simple in the code example.

Comment: Indeed, your class now subclasses the `threading.thread` class, whose `start()` method opens a new thread and executes the `run()` method. The problem with your previous implementation was that you were running the consumer in the current thread.  The consumer enters an infinite loop (waiting for message events) so of course nothing past that line would be executed.

Comment: Yes, in hindsight, that is very obvious. I just assumed that the Pika implementation would somehow get past this since I'm guessing very few people actually want their RabbitMQ consumers to block everything else. Anyway, this was quite easy to get past, hopefully it can help someone else in the future too. Thanks @ktbiz!

Comment: In the multithreading pattern `start()` opens a new thread and executes `run()`, which is the user-implemented work function (often blocking). You should not find yourself implementing a `start()` method. You implement `run()` and then you call `start()` on the containing thread object.  In this case you've subclassed thread, but you could also instantiate a `thread` object, passing it your object that implements `run()` and then call `start()` on the thread, which will fork and then call `run()` on your object. E.g:  `t = threading.Thread(myConsumer); t.start()` << won't block current thread